# Failed to change VM's activity state to HLT in VMX

Tags: linux, x86, virtualization

I am studying Intel VMX, and wrote a Linux kernel module to run a VM.
The VM will execute 'hlt' instruction, and VMExit of 12 happens.
But after VMExit, the 'activity state' is 0, not 1. I checked the MSR of 0x485, it is 0x401E0, which means bit[6:8] are all 1, HLT state is supported.
Why isn't the activity state is NOT 1, when VM runs 'hlt' instruction?

Answer (score 1):

The vm exit occurs *before* the halt instruction is executed. If you want to enter the guest in a halt state, set the activity state and resume the guest.

If you turn off halt exiting, the guest will enter the halt state. If you have interrupt exiting enabled, when the vm exit occurs due to the next interrupt, you will see the activity state is ‘halted’.

Comment: Excellent answer.   
I validated it in 2 aspects as you said.  
1. turn off halt exiting. And ext int exiting will check if active state is 1, if it is, print it and quit.  
2. re-run the guest just after the quit from 1. Normally, this run will fail at first instruction, for the activity state is '1'. It needs to set the activity state to '0' at every beginning of the VM, the guest could be started well. 

May I ask one more question on 'activity state'? How can I put the logical processor to 3 (Wait-IPI) state, just set 3 to the activity state or there needs another special way?